# JS group array values by groups with two different arrays and sum values

Tags: javascript

I am having two arrays

```
array1 =['0-18''18-19','18-19','18-19','20-22']
```

each array1 have value in the second array

```
array2=['100','200','300','400','500']
```

I want output like

```
array1 =['0-18''18-19','20-22']
array2=['100','900','500']
```

Please help on this fill this 2 arrays.
In Javascript

Comment: Can you explain why each array will have the final value.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I'm not asking why you need to do it, but why are the results the way they are. Why will array2 be `['100','900','500']`

Comment: Sorry.Actually array1 has correspond value in array 2.   when we group array 1 we have to sum the array 2 values also based on grouping.

Comment: There should be an "edit" link under the question.  It's considered good form on StackOverflow to edit your question with information prompted by the comments so that the question itself contains enough information to answer it.   The bit about summing the values in the second array is  valuable context here.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is loop through `array1` and add the elements as keys in an object. Object keys are unique so this will get rid of duplicates. As you do that you can add the corresponding element from `array2`.

```js
let array1 =['0-18','18-19','18-19','18-19','20-22']
let array2=['100','200','300','400','500']

let sums = array1.reduce((obj, key, index) => {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = 0   // if we haven't added the key, do it and set it to zero
    obj[key] += Number(array2[index])            // now add the amount from array2 
    return obj
}, {})

console.log(Object.keys(sums))    // the unique keys will be in the keys of the object
console.log(Object.values(sums))  // the sums will be in the values
```

Comment: While using the code getting the error on console.log(object.values(sums))  -   TypeError: Object.values is not a function

Comment: `Object` should have a uppercase”o”. If that’s not the problem, include the error.

Comment: Yes I have used O upper case but still get the error as ---- TypeError: Object.values is not a function

Comment: @t_azmathulla Are using Internet Explorer?

Comment: Mark - I am using the chrome

Comment: Hmm not sure why you would get that error. Does the snippet above work when you run it?

Comment: yes it working But when assign back the values to array2 =Object.values(sums)

Comment: Object.keys(sums).map(k => sums[k]); ..I used like this it worked thanks alot Mark.Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Mark Meyer is great.

I would like to point out something else about your requirements, though.

Your initial data structure looks less than ideal.  It uses two separate arrays used to hold related pieces of data that are linked only by a shared index.  I'll suggest several alternatives just below, but first, I'd like to point out that suggesting that this might be required because an external system gives you this structure as output or requires it as input doesn't help.  External systems might dictate their inputs and outputs, but you can always transform it to whatever works for you in between.

### Better formats

The shared index data format is problematic for several reasons: it is easy to get out of sync, it is much less explicit, and it almost never really describes your underlying problem domain.

Any of these would likely be a better structure for your data:

```
// Format 1
[
  {"0-18":  "100"},
  {"18-19": "200"},
  {"18-19": "300"},
  {"18-19": "400"},
  {"20-22": "500"}
]

// Format 2
[
  ["0-18",  "100"],
  ["18-19", "200"],
  ["18-19", "300"],
  ["18-19", "400"],
  ["20-22", "500"]
]

// Format 3
[
  {range: "0-18",  value: "100"},
  {range: "18-19", value: "200"},
  {range: "18-19", value: "300"},
  {range: "18-19", value: "400"},
  {range: "20-22", value: "500"}
]
```

The first format is still pretty weak.  It does eliminate the shared index problem.  But it is not all that easy to work with.  The second one is easier to work with.  But the code that does work with it will need to supply some information missing from the data, namely that the range is the first member of each pair and the value is second, via something like `pair[0]` and `pair[1]` or with functions that destructure the array into named values: `const foo = ([range, value]) => ...`  This is, again, not ideal.

The third format is by far the most explicit.  It directly links the two pieces of data in each set without relying on you to match indices.  And it also tells you directly what those two pieces represent.  This might not be the best format for storage, as it takes more space, but it is easiest for working with.

### Converting to this format

If the data is coming from a system outside your control, you might not be able to change it directly, but you can still transform it within your code.  Here is a snippet which will create `Format 3` from `array1` and `array2`:

```
const data = array1.map((range, idx) => ({range, value: array2[idx]}))
```

### Correcting internal data types

There's still one thing wrong with this format.  We want to do arithmetic on the `value`s.  But right now they are stored as strings.  We really should convert them to numbers.  A slight change to that snippet will fix this:

```
const data = array1.map((range, idx) => ({range, value: Number(array2[idx])}))
```

and this will give us

```
// Format 4
[
  {range: "0-18",  value: 100},
  {range: "18-19", value: 200},
  {range: "18-19", value: 300},
  {range: "18-19", value: 400},
  {range: "20-22", value: 500}
]
```

### Transforming this data

We can now write a bit of code similar to Mark's, but simpler because we're starting with a more explicit data structure:

```
const sums = data.reduce((res, {range, value}) => {
  res[range] = (res[range] || 0) + value
  return res
}, {})
```

Or, if we're going to use this in multiple places, we can write a reusable function:

```
const transform = (data) => data.reduce((res, {range, value}) => {
  res[range] = (res[range] || 0) + value;
  return res
}, {})
// ... later ...
const sums = transform(data)
```

### Converting back to separate arrays

If you do need the results in two separate arrays, this works just as in Mark's answer:

```
const newArray1 = Object.keys(sums)
const newArray2 = Object.values(sums)
```

(or if you need to turn the total values back into strings, you can do

```
const newArray2 = Object.values(sums).map(String)
```

Comment: While using the code getting the error on console.log(object.values(sums)) - TypeError: Object.values is not a function – t_azmathulla 10 secs ago

Comment: If `Object.values` is not available (generally [just in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)), it's fairly easy to shim, or just write your own function, something like `vals = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k])`... then `vals(sums)`.